# Applying star style to checkbox in Android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-widget, styles, android-xml

```
style="?android:attr/starStyle"
```

After applying this code to checkbox attributes, I cant view the checkbox. Is there an error in code?

Answer (score 11):

Post your full xml file. It is working for me:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/starStyle"
    android:text="CheckBox" 
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

check below code it may help you...

in your layout file where your check box...

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/Check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="  Not connected "
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ccc"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:button="@drawable/check"/>
```

in R/drawable/check.xml - use your star images here instead of my image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_checked="true" 
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/check_on" />

    <item 
        android:state_checked="false" 
        android:state_window_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/check_off" />
</selector>
```